# $C^r$-embedding of $[0,\infty)$ into $M$ (Hirsch's exercise)

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

The following exercise corresponds to 2. of Chapter 1, Section 3 of Hirch's book *Differential topology*.

Let $M$ be a connected non-compact Hausdorff manifold (without boundary) of class $C^r$. Then, there exists a closed $C^r$-embedding of $[0,\infty)$ into $M$.

I have been thinking of this exercise some days and, the more I think about it, the weirder I find it. I have decided to consider $M=\mathbb R^n$. Then the inclusion $[0,1]\hookrightarrow\mathbb R^m$ as $t\mapsto (t,0,\dots,0)$ is clearly a topological embedding. However, the image is not a topological submanifold (without boundary). Then, how could it be a $C^r$-embedding?

In fact, if such a embedding exists, $[0,\infty)$ would be a manifold (without boundary), according to Theorem 3.1.

Am I misunderstanding something or is the exercise wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$M$ may be a manifold without boundary, but $[0,\infty)$ is not, and neither it nor its image are expected to be. That is, the $C^r$-embedding of $[0,\infty)$ into $M$ is intended to be a $C^r$-embedding for manifolds *with boundary*, of which manifolds without boundary are a sub-category
.

Comment: But this exercise is stated before Hirsch introducing manifolds with boundary. That is what confuses me. We should not be allowed yo talk abound boundaries yet.

Comment: Sounds like the exercise is misplaced, then. For now, you can interpret it to mean that the restriction to $(0,\infty)$ is a $C^r$-embedding, while the full map is a closed homeomorphism.